# Intersection and product of principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> I'm trying to show that $(x)\cap(p^n)=(xp^n)$, where $x,p$ are elements of some ring $R$, $p$ is prime and $p\nmid x$.

The inclusion from right to left is obvious, but I can't make any progress in the other direction. Given an element $r\in(x)\cap(p^n)$ I get $r=ax=bp^n$ for certain $a,b\in R$ and hence that $p\mid a$ since by assumption $p\nmid x$ and $p$ is prime. So I have that $r=cxp=bp^n$ for some $c\in R$, but what now?

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is a domain?

Comment: @Crostul If it is necessary then yes.

Comment: $cxp=bp^n\implies cx=bp^{n-1}$ (if $R$ is an integral domain), and so on.

Comment: @user26857 Well that is the obvious way to proceed but why is this possible. Wouldn't $p$ need an inverse in $R$? Does an integral domain give an inverse for every prime element?

Comment: $cxp=bp^n\implies p(cx-p^{n-1})=0$.

Comment: @user26857 Oh, ok. The exercise didn't mention that $R$ needs to be an integral domain, but it seems like this is the crucial part. Thank you for clarifying.